# mmc could not create the snap in error when launching internet information services

Tags: iis, iis-5

I am getting this error when trying to run internet information services on a Virtual Machine running windows XP. Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was able to get the solution from somewhere else and here it is:

```
regsvr32 %windir%\system32\inetsrv\inetmgr.dll
```

Comment: Worked for me too, thanks!  Now I wish I understood how it became un-registered, but I doubt I'll ever know.

Comment: This also worked for me. My circumstance was this: 
1) VS 2008 installed without IIS. 
2) IIS installed. 
3) VS 2008 SP1 installed. 
4) aspnet_regiis - i command executed. 
5) snap-in didn't work. 

Issuing regsvr32 command fixed it.

Comment: needs to be run in Administrator mode